# Is there a way to target a specific user with Facebook Ads or by Facebook App with Facebook Ads API used?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

A Facebook Ads does not necessarily have to target a specific user, but at least a way to target a user's Facebook friends with Facebook Ads.

I believe it is not possible to target Facebook friends with Facebook Ads with the default setting.

But would it be possible to target Facebook friends, if I create a Facebook App with Facebook Ads API?

It would be great if I can get an advice on how to target a user's Facebook friends with Facebook Ads!

Answer (score 1):

I went to : http://www.facebook.com/ads/create/ to see what type of targeting is available. And it appears that there is such a check box.

`Friends of Connections:[_] Only show my ad to friends of users of {app Name}`

You can set this attribute following the directions here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/ On that page search for "friends_of_connections".